# Undefined symbols for architecture error occurred

Tags: ios, xcode6, cocoapods, oauth2client

I got error when debugging iOS application and am stuck all day.

What I did is:

1. install OAuth2Client library via cocoapods.
2. create viewcontroller to show google login page.
3. got the following error when debugging.

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NXOAuth2Request", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GXLoginGoogleViewController.o
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NXOAuth2AccountStore", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GXLoginGoogleViewController.o
>     "_NXOAuth2AccountStoreErrorKey", referenced from:
>         ___54-[GXLoginGoogleViewController setupOAuth2AccountStore]_block_invoke60 in GXLoginGoogleViewController.o
>     "_NXOAuth2AccountStoreAccountsDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
>         -[GXLoginGoogleViewController setupOAuth2AccountStore] in GXLoginGoogleViewController.o
>     "_NXOAuth2AccountStoreDidFailToRequestAccessNotification", referenced from:
>         -[GXLoginGoogleViewController setupOAuth2AccountStore] in GXLoginGoogleViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have already searched many similar topics but I could not resolved yet.

Can anyone suggest any direction to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[So when I downloaded the project from github](https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client), the first thing I noticed was that the project settings weren't set up very intuitively:

[image: These Settings Should Be Changed]

The "$" in the Target's Architecture column should be switched to specify iOS Standard Architectures:

[image: To iOS standard architectures]

And at that point you should be able to build and run on the device.  If you want to support the simulator as well, you'll need to add in "`i386`" as an architecture.